# Match the substring inside a string with escaped quotes using regexp

Tags: python, regex

I have string like this,

```
filter = "emails.type==\"work\""
```

The regexp i have written to group different things,

```
matchobj = re.search(r"(\w+)(\.)?(\w+)?(==|!=|(like|LIKE))(.*[^\\])", filter)
```

testing,

```
print("group1 ", matchobj.group(1))
    print("group2 ", matchobj.group(2))
    print("group3 ", matchobj.group(3))
    print("group4 ", matchobj.group(4))
    print("group5 ", matchobj.group(5))
```

result,

```
group1  emails
group2  .
group3  type
group4  ==
group5  None
```

The issue is with group 5, which is returning **None** and expected value for group 5 is **"work"** with quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to remove the parenthesis around `like|LIKE` because it creates another capturing group. So you have 6 groups instead of 5.

```
(\w+)(\.)?(\w+)?(==|!=|like|LIKE)(.*[^\\])
```

[try it](https://regex101.com/r/RZzP6z/1)